# Check which Python version Pandas is accessing

Tags: python, pandas, pip

My system is claiming that pandas requires a different Python, even though, that Python version is what's installed. How do I check which version of Python is being accessed by Pandas?

```
quinn@quinn-Lemur:~$ sudo -H pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/distpackages (0.25.3)
ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.5.3'

quinn@quinn-Lemur:~$ python3 --version 
Python 3.5.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it says you have version `3.5.2` which is not high enough since `3.5.3` is needed.

Try upgrading your Python first.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that on my Ubuntu 16.04, upgrading to 3.5.3 (or even 3.6) is a non-trivial matter. Alas.